# How do I add an XSD fragment to a schema?

Tags: .net, xml, .net-4.0, xsd

I'm trying to validate a fragment of an `XmlDocument` against an XSD that only represents that fragment.  For instance:

```
<!-- Validate entire message against message.xsd -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Message>
    <Header>
        ...
    </Header>
    <Body>
        <!-- Validate this against body.xsd -->
        ...
    </Body>
</Message>
```

The entire message is validated against the developer-supplied **message.xsd** schema.  The contents of the `<Body>` element are validated against the client-supplied **body.xsd** schema.

The **body.xsd** schema knows nothing of the `<Message>`, `<Header>` or `<Body>` elements.  It only defines what should be contained within the `<Body>` element.

I can't work out how to validate an XML fragment against an XML schema fragment.  Everything seems to suggest the XML schema fragment is required to know all about its ancestor elements.  I have a couple of paths in mind but am not sure how to implement them.

1. Programatically inject the **body.xsd** into the appropriate node of the **message.xsd**.
2. Extract the appropriate `XmlElement` from the `XmlDocument` and create a new `XmlDocument` based on this node.
3. Something to do with namespaces, which I'm yet to understand.

What solutions exist for this problem?

Comment: Have you tried importing one schema into the other? See the **import** tag from http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema namespace.

Comment: I think I see how to use the `<import>` element.  I'd declare an element of `type="my:body"` and inform the client to specify that in the **body.xsd**.  Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about the native .NET APIs for schema validation, but its quite common to find that validation APIs aren't flexible enough to allow you to validate an element other than the root. One way to do it is to invoke the validation using a schema-aware XQuery processor (for example Saxon-EE), using the query

```
import schema ... at "body.xsd";
validate strict {/Message/Header/Body}
```